# Connecting android app to server?

Tags: php, android, registration

I am working on an android app that basically brings functionality of a website to android. What I would like to do is to allow a user to sign up to the website from the android app. I think I should a use a service but I would like to take precautions to prevent the service from being abused, i.e. someone flooding with many fake accounts.  Does anyone have any suggestions? What should I do on the app or on the service to prevent this? I though about using a captcha generated on the server but I would like to avoid that.

Edit--

I need to be able to create new user from the app, so I'm worried someone will figure out how I connect to the server and they will just start creating many new users. I am thinking on doing this with a post request but i am not sure if I should

Edit--

It just came to my mind that I should limit the requests coming from an IP address. Do cellphones share IP addresses or are they all unique?

Comment: Your concern is that an authentication wouldn't be enough insurance? Or am i misunderstanding your question? Is your question actually how to connect to the server/service and retrieve data from it?

Comment: If people are able to create new users from a website, and didn't spam your server so far, most likely they won't from an android app either. I'm using http post request as well for both authentications, queries and data modifications, so far without any harm or problem.

Comment: In the website I have a captcha. I don't know how likely is that they will spam it. But I would like to prevent the situation where hundreds, thousands or more users are created from a bot. The main problem I see here is that I need to modify data without authentication. Once a user is authenticated is a lot safer. But I need to make sure that the request to create a new user is coming from the android app.

Comment: The most easy way to do that is to see the request headers on server side, or add a new parameter to each call from your android app, that would tell the server where the request came from. i'd go with the request headers though.

Comment: I've read that headers can be manipulated. Is that true?

Comment: well, it is, but not that straightforward (neither backward-compatible ;) ). If you are still worried, then you should send an extra parameter, like a hashcode made using say the userName, password and current timestamp. On server side you check if that parameter exists and holds correct data, and if everything is fine, you create the new user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView inside your mobile application, through this you don't need to get worried about authentication as you are already doing it in your web application.